# How to parse this type soap array response in android

Tags: android, ksoap2

I want to parse option tag with name tag in android and i want to this type parsing of arraylist data this
 [[anyType{}],[Man,Kid,Women,Maddy],[Sandy]]

```
AuthenticateResponse
    {
      Options=anyType
      {
         Form=anyType
          {
           Name=Form;id=12; option=anyType{};
          }; 
        Form=anyType
          {
        Name=Form1 ;id=13; 
       option=anyType
           {
           Name=Man;Id=167;Value=textview;Select=male,female 
           };
       option=anyType
           {
          Name=Kid;Id=157;Value=checkbox;Select=graduate,postgraduate 
           };
        option=anyType
           {
           Name=Women;Id=147;Value=textview;Select=lower,upper 
           };
        option=anyType
           {
           Name=Maddy;Id=167;Value=textview;Select=male,female 
           };
         }; 

     Form=anyType
          {
           Name=Form;id=17;
         option=anyType
           {
        Name=Sandy;Id=187;Value=checkbox;Select=door,close 
           };
          }; 

    }; 
    };
```

please help me out