# Parse Ksoap response array in android

Tags: android, ksoap2

I want to parse my Ksoap response array but not getting it

**Response** when debug app:

```
events_data {
    events = [events {
            groom = sanskaar;
            bride = saumya;
            event_name = wedding;
            venue = New Delhi;
            event_date = Tuesday April 14, 2014;
        },
        events {
            groom = sanskaar;
            bride = saumya;
            event_name = hzbrgbj;
            venue = New Delhi;
            event_date = Tuesday April 14, 2014;
        },
        events {
            groom = sanskaar;
            bride = saumya;
            event_name = wedding;
            venue = New Delhi;
            event_date = Tuesday April 14, 2014;
        }
    ];
}
```

Code using to parse response:

```
SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
                //SoapObject response  = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
                System.out.print(response);
                int count = response.getPropertyCount();
                System.out.print(count);


                for(int i=0;i<response.getPropertyCount();i++){    
                       Object property = response.getProperty(i);
                       if(property instanceof SoapObject){
                           SoapObject final_object = (SoapObject) property;

                           //Parsing response data
                           Event_data.put("groom", final_object.getProperty("groom").toString());


                           System.out.print(Event_data);//testing of response data
                    }
                }
```

**(property instanceof SoapObject)** Giving `false`. Code does not parse response.

While i am parsing this following response with same activity code its working good:

```
data {
    user = user {
        id = 39;
        user_name = ;
        email = ;
        phone = 7827701616;
        address = ;
        url = ;
        user_role = 1;
        plan = 1;
        verification_pin = 18053;
        status = 1;
        android_id = 38d23c7201b21f93;
    };
}
```

Help me with this.

Comment: not getting any error or exception @sais!! code is working but can't get parsed output in first response but for Second response its working awesome

Comment: I can find the Square Brace like [], try to parse this array. This will be the issue i think.

Comment: i have no idea how to parse that array. That's exact i want to know

Answer (score 0):

Try this code buddy:

```
SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
            //SoapObject response  = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
            System.out.print(response);
            int count = response.getPropertyCount();
            System.out.print(count);


            for(int i=0;i<response.getPropertyCount();i++){    
                   Object property = response.getProperty(i);
                   if(property instanceof SoapObject){
                       SoapObject final_object = (SoapObject) property;
    for(int j=0; j<final_object.getPropertyCount();j++){

  Object final_property = final_object.getProperty(j);
                   if(final_property instanceof SoapObject){
                       SoapObject array_object = (SoapObject) final_property;

       //Parsing response data
                             Event_data.put("groom",array_object.getProperty("groom").toString());
    }
}                  
   System.out.print(Event_data);//testing of response data
                }
            }
```

Comment: when i am debugging my program it doesn't enter in if condition at if(property instanceof SoapObject) when i print (property instanceof SoapObject) i got false

Answer (score 0):

Read this:

[How to parse this type soap array response in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790532/how-to-parse-this-type-soap-array-response-in-android)

According to the other posts the response should be as given below, Kindly check it,

```
events_data {
events = events {
        groom = sanskaar;
        bride = saumya;
        event_name = wedding;
        venue = New Delhi;
        event_date = Tuesday April 14, 2014;
    };
    events {
        groom = sanskaar;
        bride = saumya;
        event_name = hzbrgbj;
        venue = New Delhi;
        event_date = Tuesday April 14, 2014;
    };
    events {
        groom = sanskaar;
        bride = saumya;
        event_name = wedding;
        venue = New Delhi;
        event_date = Tuesday April 14, 2014;
    };

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve my problem by using `VECTOR`

**Code:**

```
ht.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();

for(int i=0;i<response.getPropertyCount();i++){    

       Vector resV = (Vector)response.getProperty(i); 
       int resVlenght = resV.size();

       for(int count = 0;count<resVlenght;count++)
       {
           HashMap<String,String> value = new HashMap<String,String>();
           String n = resV.elementAt(count).toString();
           SoapObject p = (SoapObject)resV.elementAt(count);
           System.out.print(n);

           String groom= p.getProperty("groom").toString();

       }

}
```